# Multiple leads to one channel of labscope

Tags: current, ground, multiplier

What would be the best thing to use to block the ground signal of a fuel injector while monitoring all 4 signals at one time attached to one channel of my labscope.The main use would be on the ground control side of an injector to see all injector waveform in a parade pattern and want to avoid each ground signal triggering the other injectors. One thought is using a diode as reverse protection or a resistor but unsure of process to work this out.I am a Master tech but by no means an electronic engineer.I want to make this a learning experience,so if I need to study something along the way please direct me to that with your response.
Thank You

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `I want to make XYZ` is not a question ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: What is a "labscope"?

Comment: Sorry that would be an oscilloscope on the electronics side, a Picoscope 4225 and 4823 on the automotive side . I use both daily.